# CacheInterceptionBehavior equivalent in dotnet core

Tags: caching, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core, interceptor

Scenario: the application has a long running method to return the data and build the final entity of a slowly changing dimension. In the previous versions of .net the data could be setup for interception and caching with the CacheInterceptionBehavior while registering the Interface with Unity.

Is there a corresponding way to do something similar in .net core?

Comment: Are you asking how to achieve something like this with ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection?

Comment: No. Interception and decoration is not supported in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection. You will have to use 3rd party container, like Unity.

Comment: @svick: Yes, that's exactly what I am looking for, achieving something similar in ASP.Net Core DI.

Comment: @Steven: Is there a sample where I can replace the ASP.Net Core DI with unity.

Comment: Take a look at the code samples in [this repository](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/Missing-Core-DI-Extensions). Although they don't contain an example of Unity, it does contain examples of most other DI Containers and how to integrate them with ASP.NET Core.

Comment: You might also find [this blog post](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2016/07/working-around-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/) informative. It talks about why you shouldn't use an adapter for you DI Container and how to approach this instead. It is basically the explanation for the previously linked repo.